# structure programme

Tags: c

i am not able to run my structure programme.
as it is getting an "constant expression required" error.
in this line:

```
 struct book_info book[i];
```

Comment: please tag your question with the appropriate language (by editing your post). that ora-xxxx error tag was unrelated. I guessed [c].

Answer (score 4):

You are almost certainly using a compiler (or a compiler mode) that does not support variable length arrays.

The ability to declare variable length arrays (VLAs) was added to C99 so, if your compiler doesn't comply with the standard, or you're compiling with something like `gcc -std=c89`, it won't work.

For example:

```
pax$ cat qq.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main (void) {
    int i = 7;
    char x[i];
    strcpy (x, "xyz");
    printf ("%s\n", x);
    return 0;
}

pax$ gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -o qq qq.c ; ./qq
xyz

pax$ gcc -std=c89 -pedantic -Wall -o qq qq.c
qq.c: In function ‘main’:
qq.c:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids variable length array ‘x’
```

Comment: ...On top of that, variable length arrays cannot be defined in file scope.

Answer (score 0):

You should use dynamic allocation. I think this is exactly what you want: 
http://fydo.net/gamedev/dynamic-arrays

Regards

Comment: This isn't good advice. You have absolutely no idea what kind of system the OP is programming in, so you cannot know whether using dynamic allocation would be suitable, superfluous or banned entirely.

Comment: Probably some details need to be added. I presumed is running Linux or Windows.

Comment: The allocation of this array is stated to be of size `i` -- there is no indication that the size of the array changes over its lifetime, and thus no need for it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

In the old C standard (C89) you could only set array length with a "constant numeric literal", ie

```
int array[100];
```

or

```
#define X 100
int array[X];
```

In the new C standard (C99) the same applies if the variable is allocated at file scope (global). But if the array is allocated at local scope (inside a function), then C99 allows you to use a non-constant value as in your example.

Comment: I think this is not helping. Probably the OP wants to resize the array dynamically from program without knowing what size the array will have at program start.

Comment: @Sacx probably you're wrong. Whether you are or not, this does help.

Comment: @Sacx As I wrote, C99 allows you to do that, as long as the array can be allocated on the stack and not the heap.